# Access 2007 form displaying only some records

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007

I have a form for entering patient data, which is bound to a number of tables, including patient, hospital, symptoms, treatment and so on. I'd asked a query previously and been advised to change the design to reduce the number of tables and therefore joins, which I've done. When I enter new data now using the form it is saved to the underlying tables correctly. However when the form is opened it is displaying only the first of 2 rows in the tables. The user will enter data in some fields but not all of them, so would the form (and the record source query under it) not be returning the next record because it does not appear in ALL the linked tables, only some? For example, all records will have a row in the Patient table, but not all will have a record in the Surgery table, yet the form needs to be able to record data for all possible fields. Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Managed to answer my own question - form does require an entry in every linked table in order to show all records. Got round this by adding a check box to allow users to specify 'no surgery' for example, which at least saves a row to the related table and allows the record to be shown. Would prefer not to have a row in a table if it's not required, but couldn't see what else to do.

Comment: For anyone who has had a similar problem, it's to do with the type of join - just changed my INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN and all patient records show regardless of whether there is data in all the associated tables.